# Remove all requests from ASINetWorkQueue

Tags: iphone, asihttprequest, nsoperationqueue

Does someone know a way to remove requests from an ASINetworkQueue in a persistent way? The reset function doesn't seem to do the job. What I'm trying to do is the following

```
- (void)fillAndRunQueue:(ASINetworkQueue*)queue requests:(NSArray*)requests {  
    for (ASIHTTPRequest* request in requests) {  
        if ([request check]) { // Valid request => add it to the queue    
            [queue addOperation:request];  
        } else { // Invalid request => cancel immediatelly  
            // HOW TO REMOVE ALL PREVIOUS REQUESTS FROM THE QUEUE??  
            return;  
        }  
    }  

    [queue go];  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two obvious options I can see are:

```
[queue cancelAllOperations];
```

or if you want more control:

```
[request cancel];
```

for each request you want to "remove" (this isn't technically removing them, but may have a close enough effect for your purposes).

Although, I think `[queue reset];` should also work - maybe you can explain exactly what happens when you try to use it?

If all else fails, releasing and then recreating the queue should remove everything.

**Update**

To further explain, I don't think it's possible to actually remove items from an NSOperationQueue, only to cancel them. (ASINetworkQueue is a subclass of NSOperationQueue.)

The apple docs are here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: First of all, thanks for replying. The problem with [queue cancelAllOperations], [queue reset] and [request cancel] (for each request) is that they all leave the number of requests in the queue unchanged. I did monitor the latter with [queue requestsCount] and it always stays the same.

Comment: To be more clear, what I want is to completely emtpy the queue. Of course releasing and recreating the queue would be an option for this, but I hoped there would be a more elegant way.

Comment: Another workaround would be to first verify all requests and then add them to the queue at once. However, the original question (how to generally remove requests from a queue) still remains.

Comment: I think the answer to that is that it is not actually possible to remove items from an NSOperationQueue - I've updated my answer to explain and link to the docs.

Comment: Yeah, seems you're right on that. I guess I'll go with the approach of validating all requests before they're actually added to the queue. Thanks a lot!